# ORA-01919: role 'RESTRICTED_ROLE1' does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I am getting this error while trying to import with `impdp`

```
expdp system/system schema=ieulive directory=data_pump dumpfile=IEULIVE2.DMP logfile=exp.log
```

at export, all good

```
imp system/system remap_schema=ieulive:ieu1 directory=dir1 dumpfile=IEULIVE2.DMP logfile=imp.log

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
ORA-39083: Object type ROLE_GRANT failed to create with error:
ORA-01919: role 'RESTRICTED_ROLE1' does not exist

Failing sql is:
 GRANT "RESTRICTED_ROLE1" TO "IEULIVE" WITH ADMIN OPTION
.
.
.
.
```

also tried with

```
expdp ieulive/ieulive directory=data_pump dumpfile=IEULIVE2.DMP logfile=exp.log

impdp ieu1/ieu1 directory=dir1 dumpfile=IEULIVE2.DMP logfile=imp.log
```

not sure what the difference between two methods, but anyway I got the same result
Help Appreciated.

Comment: You have to create the role restricted_role1 on target db before run the impdp.

Comment: Because schema export does not export roles.

Comment: @prifor creating role manually did work, but what about the `expdp system/system schema=ieulive`, this also considered a schema export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@scapy answered the question in the question comment, I bosted the answer to accept as solution.

```
create role restricted_role1;
```

then import.